# Replace NULL with the values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have a requirement as shown below.

There are 6 item_class - A,B,C,D,A1A,A1B which should appear for all the records.

Record:

```
Item_class Rev_id
A            1
B            1
C            2
D            1
Null         1
Null         2
```

We need to display the record as given below table,

```
item_class     Rev_id
A               1
B               1
C               2
D               1
A1A             1
A1B             2
```

So all the item_class(A,B,C,D,A1A,A1B) should display when item class is null and also it checks if item_clas A,B,C are already present then for different rev_id it will display the remaining one (i.e. D,A1A,A1B) but all item_class should covered.

How can we write a query to fetch similar records?

Comment: You should first show of what you have tried, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't follow the logic by which you assigned `A1A` and `A1B` to those `NULL` slots.  If the `Rev_id` were the same for all records, I could sort of see a way of doing it, but without a common group I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: we have tried using case statement but didn't work, select case when item_class is not null and rev_id is not null then item_class when item_class is null and rev_id is not null then ? end item_class, rev_id from test_class where rev_id = 1; here for ?, need to check if item_class A is already available for rev_id 1 then display item_class B, if item_class B is available for rev_id 1 then display item_class C for rev_id etc. we want the query in that manner

Comment: Where do `rev_id` values come from? Where do the `item_class` come from? What determines the order of the result set? If you want an answer you need to explain your requirements properly.

Comment: there are 2 tables, test_class and class_details. In test_class the records are given in above table. for class_details, the data is                    
item_class - A,B,C,D,A1A,A1B and description is null. Again we have written the query as, select item_class,rev_id from test_class a, class_details b where a.item_class(+) = b.item_class, so I can fetch all the item_class from class_details table.

Comment: Instead of providing details in the comments, can you please update the question with the relevant details.

Answer (score -1):

the issue got resolved by using outer join. Please find below,

```
select b.item_class,
       a.rev_id
from   cct_test a 
       right outer join cct_item_details b
       on a.item_class = b.item_class and a.rev_id = 1;
```

Output:

```
item_class | rev_id
A          |  1
C          |  1
A1B        |  null
A1A        |  null
D          |  null     
B          |  null
```